# How to make a sequential number columns in Vaadin

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7, vaadin-grid

I  created a  table in vaadin. I am selecting columns from the database. I need a column which sequentially gives number to every row.

I am using the

```
  Table table = new Table();
```

For Grid:

```
 GeneratedPropertyContainer wrappingContainer = new GeneratedPropertyContainer(container);
            wrappingContainer.addGeneratedProperty("rowHeader", new PropertyValueGenerator<Long>();

 table.setContainerDataSource(wrappingContainer);
        table.setColumnOrder("rowHeader", "name", "surname");

  layout.addComponent(table);
```

Comment: The simplest would be to modify your sql query to generate a now number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a generated Column for that:

```
table.addGeneratedColumn("index", new ColumnGenerator(){
    @Override
    public Object generateCell(final Table source, final Object itemId, final Object columnId)
    {
        Container.Indexed container = (Container.Indexed) source.getContainerDataSource();
        return Integer.toString(container.indexOfId(itemId));
    }
});

// add it to the start of the visible columns
table.setVisibleColumns("index", /* other columns ... */);
```

You get the row number from the container.
The table though has to work with a Container that implements the Indexed sub-interface, for example BeanItemContainer or IndexedContainer.

This is what you do using the Grid:

```
// the GeneratedPropertyContainer is a decorator for the original container
final GeneratedPropertyContainer gpc = new GeneratedPropertyContainer(container);
grid.setContainerDataSource(gpc);
gpc.addGeneratedProperty("index", new PropertyValueGenerator<String>(){
    @Override
    public String getValue(final Item item, final Object itemId, final Object propertyId)
    {
        // get the index from the original container
        final Container.Indexed indexContainer = (Container.Indexed) container;
        return Integer.toString(indexContainer.indexOfId(itemId));
    }

    @Override
    public Class<String> getType()
    {
        return String.class;
    }
});

// ...

grid.setColumnOrder("index", /* the other property IDs... */);
```

If you use a `PropertyValueGenerator<Long>` you need to set a `NumberRenderer` for that type. `grid.getColumn("index").setRenderer(new NumberRenderer("%d"));` will do the trick.

Comment: With the Grid you use the GeneratedPropertyContainer for that purpose. You put your container in the generated one, add your cell similar to the solution above with `addGeneratedProperty` and set the Grid's container to the GeneratedPropertyContainer.

Comment: thanks for the edits ... i am getting all the columns with the index column but not getting the data inside it.

Comment: Am I right, that you only see the column with the indices? If so you need to setup the other columns in the original container, as you did before. If that doesn't help, post your container setup in your question too, so I can have a better look at the possible glitch.